# From char * to Handle

Tags: c++, pointers, handle, inter-process-communicat

I want to send pipe handle to the other processes. To send the pointer, i converted it to the string.

```
   sprintf(handleToChar, "%p", handle);
```

so if value of handle is `0x00043c` i get a memory with `"00043c"`. I send it.

I receive it in the right form of `"00043c"`.

I am unable to convert it back. I tried using sprintf again, but that is wrong as i realized later.

```
 sprintf((char*)handle, "%s", handleToChar); // <-- wrong
```

i thought `atoi` would do but there can be characters too in the string. so it failed again.

How can i do it ?

Comment: This is simply not how it works. Read up on Virtual Address spaces - every process has its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't. Addresses can't be shared between processes.

If you want to share a resource between two processes, you have to create a shared resource, or save/send other data so that the other process can create its own handle.

Comment: actually pipes are also handles in windows, so i need to send the pipe handle to other process.

Comment: @AshishNegi No you don't send the handle, you create a named pipe and send the *name* of that pipe to the other process. The other process then creates it's end of the pipe using that name, and get its own unique handle.

Answer (score 0):

Try boost interprocess, you can create shared memory